# Using PyQt from IronPython

Tags: ironpython, pyqt

Is it possible to use PyQt from IronPython?

From what I've read IronPython should work with CPython compatible libraries but out of the box it doesn't seem to work.

If it is possible, will code completion work?

Answer (score 3):

You can't import CPython modules from IronPython directly. There is a project which tries to provide a way to do this: http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/, but I'm not sure if they support PyQT already.

On the other hand, you might try using WPF instead of PyQT. I used both, and I find WPF superior in every way.

My current GUI app is based on IronPython + WPF and it's a dream to program.

Answer (score 2):

Hope someone else who spent more time messing around with this comes by and gives you qualified, ambiguous answer, but here is some questionable insight from my personal experience:

PyQt relates to cPython in a way that is very different than .Net relates to IronPython.

While IronPython is built on TOP of .Net, PyQt is a BINARY, semi-automatically generated set of bindings specific to a version of cPython against which it was compiled.

For a variety of reasons, i have problems running "standard" BINARY python modules against IronPython. Only the pure-Python modules that can be interpreted by IronPython as "Python" would ever work for me.

I am not saying "it can't be done," but I do expect you to have very bad experience with the set up if you manage to compile and install PyQt into IronPython.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use pyqt/pyside with ironpython.

You could probably use [qyoto](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto)(the c#/.net binding for qt) unfortunatly it looks like its not nearly as often used/well supported/etc. as pyqt/pyside.