# Import PyQt in IronPython

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, ironpython

Is it possible to use PyQt4 in IronPython? if so, how can I do it.

I already have a project created in PyQt4 that runs on linux. I need to create the same project on Windows using IronPython. If I could use PyQt in IronPython, I could simply move the code.

Please Help.

I use Python 2.7 and IronPython 2.7 with VS2010.

Comment: Does it have to be IronPython? PyQt probably does not work without an effort in IronPython ([see this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3483492/468244)) but should work with CPython-based implementations for Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to be ironPython as I need to import a .NET based dll file and use its functions.